# Entering the US under a B2 visa

Tags: usa

When reading the latest version of the proclamation, it seems to me that B2 visa holders are actually allowed to enter the US at this point [1] or am I missing something? Thanks.

[1] https://www.nafsa.org/regulatory-information/covid-19-restrictions-us-visas-and-entry

Comment: Questions about B-2 visas (and temporary visits in general) belong on [Travel.SE].  B-2 visitors are not banned in general, but they *are* banned if they have been present in any of several places in the 14 days before they arrive in the United States.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about short-term travel.

Answer (score 1):

With specific exceptions, foreign nationals (including B2 visa holders) who have been in any of the following countries during the past 14 days may not enter the United States:

- China
- Iran
- European Schengen area (Austria, Belgium, Czech Republic,
  Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland,
  Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta,
  Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain,
  Sweden, Switzerland, Monaco, San Marino, Vatican City)
- United Kingdom
  (England, Scotland, Wales, Northern Ireland)
- Republic of Ireland
- Brazil

source: https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/from-other-countries.html

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is misleading.  It doesn't matter whether the traveler *is from* from such a country, but whether the traveler *has been in* the country.  For example, a traveler from Iceland who hasn't been in any of the named countries in the last 14 days is not covered by the restriction. On the other hand, a traveler who is from South Africa who *has* been in any of the named countries in the last 14 days *is* covered by the restriction and cannot enter the US (unless the traveler qualifies for one of the exceptions, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Edited to clarify the answer.